# Get UITextField keyboard propositions

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I would like to know how to get the first UITextField's keyboard suggestion (咖啡 in the screenshot). I haven't find anything that allow me to get the Chinese characters before the user press the return key.

I know the following methods

```
_tagField.textInRange(_tagField.markedTextRange)

textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)
```

But they just return what the user is typing (in pinyin in my case).

Getting just the typed pinyin is useless for me because there are multiple Chinese characters for a given pinyin.

Any idea?

[image: iOS Keyboard propositions for Chinese input]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. UILexicon is only for custom keyboard extension. I just want to handle suggestions from the iOS Keyboard (just for Chinese input), not develop a custom keyboard.

Comment: What do you want to do with the suggestions? I made a custom keyboard previously, so I know quite well that Apple gives you access to almost nothing from their system keyboard. I can't say for sure that you're unable to grab the first suggestion, but considering they don't even give you access to their autocorrect, it seems like other pinyin choices are right up there with autocorrect.

Comment: I just want to get the chinese characters while the user is typing it in pinyin. Often you can type a lot of letters before picking a suggestion. For example : the user type beijingjiaotongdax, the suggestion will be 北京交通大学 but I can't know it before the user pick it. I need it to display a tag list corresponding to what the user is typing.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but if the iOS keyboard is providing you with the suggestion, why do you need access to it? If the user types shuijiao, it's gonna give you 睡觉 and 水饺. Do you need all the suggestions? Or just the most common one? What do you need to do differently than the system keyboard is what I'm wondering.

Comment: @PeYoTlL have you found a solution to this?